# python socket, HTTPS request load full html code

Tags: python, html, sockets, http, https

I'm learning how to use socket to make https request, and my problem is that I can success request (status 200), but I will only have a part of the webpage content (can't understand why it's splitted in this way)

I will receive my Http header, with a part of the html code. I tried it with at least 3 different website (including github), and I always have the same result.

I'm able to connect with my account to a website, having my cookies to use my account, load a new page with those cookie and get a status 200, and juste have a part of the website... Like just having site's navbars.

If someone have any clue.

```
import socket
import ssl

HOST = 'www.python.org'
PORT = 443

MySock = socket.socket()
MySock = ssl.wrap_socket(MySock, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
MySock.connect((HOST,PORT))
MySock.send("""GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: {}

""".format(HOST).encode())

#Create file to check reponse content
with open('PythonOrg.html', 'w') as File:
    print(MySock.recv(50000).decode(), file=File)
```

Answer (score 0):

1) I seem to not be able to load content with a large buffer, in `MySock.recv(50000)`, I need to loop with smaller buffer, like 4096, and concatenate a variable.

2) A request required time to receive the entire response, I used time.sleep function to manage this waiting, not sur if it's the best way with an ssl socket to wait the server. If anyone have a nice way to get the entire response message when it's big, feel free.